# Как можно получить значение id в svg нижней линии

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте
Есть SVG файл, это график, в нём множество линий, каждая из которых означаем движение объекта из одной точки в другую.Эти линии могут налагаться друг на друга. Необходимо по нажатию мышки на линию получить название или идентификатор линии не только на которую нажимаю, но и последующие нижние. Просмотр HTML страницы с SVG осуществляется в IE/
Для реализации встраиваю в SVG сценарий на JavaScript. Значение, координаты верхней линии получаю без проблем, а вот с нижними не могу понять как сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста, может у кого-то есть идеи, или может кто-то уже сталкивался с похожей задачей?

```
<polyline points=" 373, 112, 392, 119" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" fill="none"   name="l1" id="1"/>
  <polyline points=" 373, 112, 392, 119" stroke="red" stroke-width="0.5" fill="none" name="l2" id="2"/>
```

Comment: нижнии - те которые перекрыты другими ? а как вы себе это представляете в принципе ?

Comment: извиняюсь возможно за неточно сформулированный вопрос,
нижнии - те которые перекрыты другими - я подразумевала несколько элементов, каждый из них перекрывает другой. По событию onClick необходимо получить ID, NAME каждого из элементов, координаты клика мыши которого находятся в области этих элементов